# Recursive forwarding Bind DNS server not answering from cache

Tags: bind, named-conf

**Problem Statement**

I have a bind caching and forwarding server that is functioning *almost* as expected.  All queries are forwarded, their TTL is cached.  At first blush, everything appeared normal until I was watching the response time never fall below the 150ms of my VPN.

Upon performing tcpdump, I found that even though bind was well aware of the TTL being geater than 0 (TTL of 14000 in this case), the resolver was still forwarding every request.  The TTL of the response **still decrements as expected**, but **every** single request is still forwarded upstream regardless of the TTL remaining in the cached record.

If I disable forwarding, this behavior ceases and cache works as expected.

**Version**

```
Bind 9.9.4-29  (Redhat forked)
OS: CentOS 7
```

**Relevant Parts of the Configuration**

```
allow-query { local; };
recursion yes;
allow-recursion { local; };
max-cache-size unlimited;
stacksize unlimited;
datasize unlimited;

    zone "." IN {
    type forward;
    forward first;
    forwarders { 192.168.120.3; 192.168.120.2; };
    };
```

I have tried both `forward first;` and `forward only;` This resolver has almost no load on it and several GB of memory available.  At any given time, it never has more than a few hundred records cached.

Is it likely that I have the wrong expectation of behavior in bind?  Using Unbound I did not see this behavior, but I would like to switch back to bind for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Problem existed between keyboard and chair.

**What went wrong**

In my troubleshooting, I was switching my /etc/resolv.conf back and forth between local and upstream resolvers.

**Root cause**

Only one cup of coffee present.  I thought I had switched back to the local resolver and I had not.  Apologies, false alarm.